# Create a csv file of a view in hive and put it in s3 with headers excluding the table names

Tags: amazon-s3, hive, hiveql

I have a view in hive named `prod_schoool_kolkata`. I used to get the csv as:

```
hive -e 'set hive.cli.print.header=true; select * from prod_schoool_kolkata' | sed 's/[\t]/,/g' > /home/data/prod_schoool_kolkata.csv
```

that was in EC2-Instance. I want the path to be in S3.
I tried giving the path like :

```
hive -e 'set hive.cli.print.header=true; select * from prod_schoool_kolkata' | sed 's/[\t]/,/g' > s3://data/prod_schoool_kolkata.csv
```

But the csv is not getting stored.

I also had a problem that the csv file is getting generated but every column head is having pattern like: `tablename.columnname` for  example `prod_schoool_kolkata.id`. Is there any way to remove the table names in the csv getting formed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to first install the  AWS Command Line Interface.

Refer the Link : [**Installing the AWS Command Line Interface**](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/installing.html) and follow the relevant installation instructions or go to the Sections at the bottom to get the installation links relevant to your Operating System(Linux/Mac/Windows etc).

After verifying that it's installed properly, you may run normal commands like cp,ls etc over the aws file system. So, you could do

```
hive -e 'set hive.cli.print.header=true; select * from prod_schoool_kolkata'|
sed 's/[\t]/,/g' > /home/data/prod_schoool_kolkata.csv

aws s3 cp /home/data/prod_schoool_kolkata.csv s3://data/prod_schoool_kolkata.csv
```

Also see [How to use the S3 command-line tool](https://openedx.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/OpenOPS/pages/25559308/How+to+use+the+S3+command-line+tool+Mac+OSX+Linux)

Comment: There is no other direct way Sir?

Comment: @VijayaSeetharaman : S3 is  a different filesystem and only way to access it  is to either have S3 bucket mounted on your server or install an interface that can access it. Check with your Techops/ OS admin  if they can get it mounted and then you may be able to access it directly. There are other modules in Java/ Python for uploading and downloading files from s3 if you are interested, apart from the command line for a programmatic approach.

Comment: Ok Sir. Is there any command for moving the data to s3 rather than copying as my ec2 instance will be loaded with lots of files.

Comment: @VijayaSeetharaman : Yes,  `aws mv` is also available. See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/mv.html

Comment: I have edited my question. If you know any solution please do help.

Comment: @Vijaya Seetharamam : Thanks for accepting the answer. This answers the original question. If you have another question, you should consider asking it separately with additional details only specific to your  problem.